# Why is my input in the Unity editor window working perfectly but not at all in the game build?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, input

I have a pretty simple script:

```
 void Start()
 {
 }
 void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown("return")){
         play();
     }
 }
 void play()
 {
     anim.SetTrigger("playbutton");
 }
```

It works wonders in the editor window, but when I build and run, absolutely nothing happens. It loads the scene just fine, but the button inputs don't seem to be getting through.

UPDATE:
I tried several different buttons, but those didn't work. I did try putting the anim.SetTrigger line in the Start function, and it didn't work either, which means that this is a problem with the animator/script, not the input.

Comment: Check the logs in your build's Assets directory & see if there are any errors. If not, try logging some things in that script and make sure the code is running.

Comment: @Klaycon What do you mean by logging something in the script?

Comment: `Debug.Log("play function executing")` etc

Comment: @Klaycon It works fine, but still only in the editor. Nothing seems to have changed in the build. I monkeyed around with some stuff but still, nothing

Comment: You say it works fine but just to confirm, you *did* check the logs for your built executable and confirm that your debug message is showing up there in those logs, and not the editor, right?

Comment: @Klaycon Ah, my bad, you're right. Although I can't find any logs (I assume a .txt file?) in the build folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217040/discussion-between-spagoni-and-klaycon).

Answer (score 0):

the script seems simple and fine , i suggest that u try the same script in an empty project to see if it works or not if it dose work try to apply the script on an other game object and run .
lets say it didn't work u can try this instead "if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)" or try to use an other key

Answer (score 0):

I'VE FOUND IT. The animation component in the object in question was set to cull completely, not always animate.